# How to manipulate the ClaimsIdentity of current token using middleware in .net core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity, .net-security

I have a middleware to use in development mode like following.

```
public class DevelopmentUserMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public DevelopmentUserMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Request.HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(
            new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "75cc7127-a31c-418b-b580-27379136b148"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Name Surname")
            }));
        
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

So I can use name or id value on development platform. And getting values using an extension method `var usriId = User.GetUserId();`.

```
public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtensions
{
    public static Guid GetUserId(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (principal == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal));
      
        return Guid.Parse(principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
    }

    public static string GetName(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (principal == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal));

        return principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
    }
}
```

But now, I am using Bearer access token while using api resource. If the user nameidenitfier is "123456" in the access token, the `User.GetUserId()` method returns "123456". My middleware does not work.

So can I change only name and nameidentifier of access token in development mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could read the claims from the conetext and modify it instead of recreate a new claims identity.

More details, you could use below codes.

```
public class DevelopmentUserMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public DevelopmentUserMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        string token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            List<Claim> claims = context.User.Claims.ToList();
            claims.Remove(claims.First(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "75cc7127-a31c-418b-b580-27379136b148"));
            claims.Remove(claims.First(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name));
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Name Surname"));
            var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, ClaimTypes.Name);
            context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
        }
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Do you use `DevelopmentUserMiddleware` before or after  `app.UseAuthentication()` in setup.cs? This did not work for me.

Comment: After the app.UseAuthentication().