# How to remove claims from current user in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a project that is written using C# on the top of ASP.NET Core 6 framework.

After agrees to specific agreement, I want to remove a claim from their current session. How can I remove specific claims from current session?

The `UserManager<>` provides a method called `RemoveClaimsAsync()` which I believes remove claims from the store not the claims in the current session.

Is it possible to remove claims from current session without signing out/in?

```
await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
await _signInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync(user, false, upddatedClaims);
```

Comment: Have you tried something like this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63610706/how-to-manipulate-the-claimsidentity-of-current-token-using-middleware-in-net-c

Comment: You can remove a claim from Identity by calling "RemoveClaim" method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.removeclaim?view=net-6.0. (e.g. (User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).RemoveClaim())

Comment: @SergeyVishnevskiy I attempted that. but does not seems to update the current session

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you should call RefreshSignInAsync(TUser) after calling RemoveClaim.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @Zephire that is the correct answer.

Comment: Converted to answer, glad to hear it sorted your issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling the `RemoveClaim` method, you can call the `RefreshSignInAsync(TUser)` method to update the Claims accordingly.

[MS Docs reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0)